# How to place mat-sidenav under the mat-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypap5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html):

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>youtube-angular</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Currently the left sidebar shown above the mat-toolbar.

What I want is to place mat-sidenav under the mat-toolbar basically the way it works on gmail. [image]

Also I want the left toolbar to behave like the one on gmail.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `top: <your_toolbar_size>px !important;` to your .sidenav class.

[image]

**Edit:**

Please see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-meopgy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html).

Comment: did you try that with stackbliz? it seems does not work

Comment: @sreginogemoh, I added a screenshot of what I think is what you want. Please make sure the css gets reloaded in stackblitz (try editing the html or something else to do so)

Comment: see the full screen, also the behavior is not that I would expect, I want it to behave like gmail, however in that case it does something different

Comment: @sreginogemoh please check the edited answer

Comment: @sreginogemoh I don't see what you need explained. I'm bascially using an example that is given in the angular mat documentation combined with a mat toolbar. The button in the toolabard calls the toggle() method of the drawer, which opens and closes it.

Comment: Just marked as an answered, it would be great if you can have a look in to the other one I've posted above

Comment: Hey there, I just noticed that the contend is controllable there. If you move the mouse wheel it will scroll and district the top toolbar. How would you fix that?

Comment: Please create a new question, we do not want to pollute this comment section

Comment: here is the one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429603/how-to-disable-the-content-area-to-move-on-mouse-scroll