# How to disable the content area to move on mouse scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a layout implemented like this [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-meopgy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html):

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button
    type="button"
    aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="drawer.toggle()">
    <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>dashboard-app</span>
</mat-toolbar>
    
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" mode="side">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    My app content
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The problem there is that when you scrolling the mouse wheel the content move up and down districting the top toolbar. How would you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the problem originates (in 'navigation.component.css'):

```css
.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can use FlexLayoutModule to more easily and reliably fill parent components.

> npm i @angular/flex-layout

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;" fxFill>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button
      type="button"
      aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
      mat-icon-button
      (click)="drawer.toggle()">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>dashboard-app</span>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container fxFill>
    <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" mode="side">
      <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      My app content
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

This worked for me, but you can probably clean it up a bit.

You can also:

- Just wrap the component with:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

- Add overflow: hidden; to the body tag in styles.css
- Hardcode the navbar height, and use 'height: calc(100% - navbarHeight);' on the component

Comment: when I removing it the left menu becomes invisible

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test that thoroughly. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: is it possible to achieve that without introducing a flex-lyaout library?

Comment: Yeah, just wrapping the component with <div style="overflow: hidden;"></div> should work too. Or hardcode the navbar height, and use height: calc(100% - navbarHeight) on the component.